# How to add date inside the <td> tag?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have this input box on my form:

```html
<td contenteditable="true" class="date"></td>
```

and I'm trying to add a date dropdown to it so what I did was:

```html
<td contenteditable="true" class="date"><input type="date"></td>
```

And now when I hit send it won't save to the database. Are there any other ways to do this?

Here's the whole code in case you need it:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" style="border-radius: 10px;" id="crud_table">
     <tr>
      <th width="30%">Requested By</th>
      <th width="10%">Start Date</th>
      <th width="10%">Employee Name</th>
      <th width="10%">Position</th>
      <th width="10%">Account</th>
      <th width="10%">Platform</th>
      <th width="45%">Processor</th>
      <th width="10%">RAM</th>
      <th width="10%">Monitor</th>
      <th width="10%">Phone</th>
      <th width="10%">Phone Type</th>
      <th width="10%">Headset</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="reqname" required></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="date"><input type="date"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="empname"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="position"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="account"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="platform"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="processor"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="ram"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="monitor"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="phone"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="phonetype"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="headset"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

PS: I get `All fields are required` when I hit send so it mean I don't get any values from the date dropdown.

Comment: You aren't really giving us much to work with.

Comment: @JCode What do you mean? Everything you need to know is right there, lol.

Comment: Some things @JCode might have been referring to: The question is tagged with PHP and MySQL, but there is no PHP code or SQL in the question at all. You said "when I hit send", but there is no indication in the HTML you have posted about how the data will be sent to PHP. Is there some JS involved? Is there a form around the table?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, he also states that he's 'sending' data but there's no form in his code.

Comment: @JCode I thought maybe `id="crud_table"` could mean that there's some kind of JS library that makes the table act like a form, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Could be, but so far we are wasting time guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a name attribute to the `<input type='date'>`. In order for an element to be sent as a parameter when submitting a form (either POST or GET) it must have a valid name attribute.

```
<input type="date" name="custom_date">
```

Answer (score 0):

input type "date" includes the year, month, and day, but not the time.

```
<input type="date" name="custom_date" class="date">
```